# How to get the PID of a process that is started from eval in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

When doing something like this in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls & echo $!
```

the pid of `ls` will be printed to the console. But when I change it to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
command="ls & echo $!"
eval "$command"
```

it'll no longer work. Why is this and is there a workaround?

Comment: Why are you using `eval` in the first place? The immediate problem is that `$!` is expanded at the time you assign to `command`, since it is in double quotes. Use single quotes instead.

Comment: The reason is that I'm trying to solve the problem described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734291/subprocesses-started-by-script-using-eval-are-not-interrupted-on-ctrlc by writing the pid to a file. Still haven't managed to get it working though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your command in background at the end of your command for `eval`:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd="ls > /dev/null &"
eval "$cmd"
eval_pid=$!
bash_pid=$$

echo bash_pid: ${bash_pid}, eval_pid: ${eval_pid}
```

Output:

```
bash_pid: 25926, eval_pid: 25927
```

To get the pid of the process launched by `eval`.

Comment: The eval returned value on OS X Ventura, `bash`, was complaining the `process XXXXX was not started by this process`.